# How to compile the svn repository?

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, apk

I develop with eclipse, Java for Android. I just installed SVN subclipse for the company. I made the repository in a cloud (maybe it is a mistake, I can change it) and we all work every one in his computer and then commit the code to the repository.

The repository is always the latest code of all the developers.

I don't find a way how to compile the repository and build an APK file. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Typically you would use some continous integration system like [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/). It can fetch the code from your svn repository (or git for that matter), and perform most anything you want. This seems like a good starting point: [Building android apps with Jenkins/Hudson](http://jenkins-ci.org/content/getting-started-building-android-apps-hudson) (even if the link is a bit old).